# rails refactoring AR query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, refactoring

I'm trying to refactor my scope, and my controller, but I feel it could be better. From the controllers perspective the new code is definitely better, but I think the `alltasks` scope and the `all_uncompleted_tasks_ordered_by_deadline` instance methods are kinda weird. Any ideas?

user:

```
has_many :assigned_tasks, class_name: "Task", foreign_key: "assigner_id", dependent: :destroy
has_many :executed_tasks, class_name: "Task", foreign_key: "executor_id", dependent: :destroy
```

task:

```
belongs_to :assigner, class_name: "User"
belongs_to :executor, class_name: "User"
scope :alltasks, -> (u) { where('executor_id = ? OR assigner_id = ?', u.id, u.id) }
scope :uncompleted, -> { where(completed_at: nil) }
```

tasks controller

```
def index
  @tasks = Task.alltasks(current_user).uncompleted.includes(:executor, :executor_profile, :assigner, :assigner_profile).order("deadline DESC")
end
```

NEW CODE:

user.rb

```
def all_uncompleted_tasks_ordered_by_deadline
  Task.alltasks(self).uncompleted.includes(:executor, :executor_profile, :assigner, :assigner_profile).order("deadline DESC")
end
```

tasks controller

```
def index
  @tasks = current_user.all_uncompleted_tasks_ordered_by_deadline
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I rather think that the `all_tasks` wants to be in the User model like the assigned and executed are already. Maybe you can move it there as method and apply the needed `Task` scopes in the controller.

say:

```
#user.rb
def all_tasks
  Task.where('executor_id = ? OR assigner_id = ?', id, id)
end

#tasks_controller.rb
def index
  @tasks = current_user.all_tasks
                       .uncompleted.includes(:executor, :executor_profile, :assigner, :assigner_profile)
                       .order(deadline: :desc)

end
```